# Recording information continuously in background

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service, background

For my application I have to create a feedback for the GPS position, the use of the RAM and the CPU.
I must also register when the application starts and when it closes.

I created the different classes to retrieve this information then I tried to create a class for the reassembly of these.
During my research to correctly create this class I encountered several problems. I followed the different tracks below.

- extends Thread
  → I do not modify the functioning of a Thread
- AsyncTask
  → AsyncTask are made for short task
- extends IntentService
  → My reassemblies are done every 500ms, too many intents
- extends Service
  → Not intended for background stains

Concerning the Runnables and the HandlerThread the problem is that I cannot detect the closing of the application

At first I turned to a service but it did not correspond 100% to my needs, now the code I use is as follows:

```
public class InfoLogRunnable implements Runnable {

    private static final String TAG       = InfoLogRunnable.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final long PAUSE_TIME  = 100;
    private static final long UPDATE_TIME = 500;
    private AtomicBoolean running         = new AtomicBoolean(true);
    private AtomicBoolean pause           = new AtomicBoolean(true);

    public void stop()  {running.set(false);}
    public void pause() {pause.set(true);}
    public void play()  {pause.set(false);}

    public void run() {
        Log.d(TAG, "running..");
        while (running.get()) {
            while (pause.get())
                doPause(PAUSE_TIME);
            doStuff();
            doPause(UPDATE_TIME);
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "stopping..");
    }

    private void doPause(long ms) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(ms)
        } catch (InteruptedException x) {
            Log.d(TAG, x);
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }

    private void doStuff() {
        // logs
    }
}
```

The problem here is that when the application closes, the `stopping` message is never displayed, which is
normal in my opinion. However, I would still like to know when the application is stopped and so when this 'service' is stopped too.

To put it simply, what is the best method for recording information (from the application or not) continuously in the background from the start of the application until it is closed.

Thank for your help !

PS: I dev for android 4.4

Activity lifecyle isn't a solution because there is not guarantee that onDestroy and/or onStop is called and Application dont have these method.
[onPause](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) method from Activity is a bad idea because its called when the activity is no longer visible

Answer (score 0):

To do this, it is better to use the Activity Life Cycle because you need your message to be displayed.

Of course, you can also use the Application Life Cycle.

To be able to use the Activity Life Cycle, call the following methods in the main activity:

To start recording information:

```
   @Override
protected void onCreate() {....}
```

or

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {....}
```

To end the recording:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() { super.onDestroy(); 
.......}
```

or

```
@Override
protected void onStop() { super.onStop(); 
.......}
```

Comment: onDestroy is not called every time for Activity so it can't work, Application lifecyle don't have onDestroy and onTerminate is for debug purpose